# Angular 2: Navigation to child default route not working

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a navigation bar at my app level that is as follows:

```
<ul>
<li id="navbar-header">Header</li>
<li class="navbar-item">
    <a routerLink="/administration"
       routerLinkActive="active">Administration</a>
</li>
<li class="navbar-item">
    <a routerLink="/web-report" routerLinkActive="active">Web Report</a>
</li>
```

I am trying to set the default of my web-report route, but for some reason it does not redirect properly and it stays on localhost:8080/web-report.

Here is my web report routing module:

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
        {path: 'web-report', component: WebReportComponent, children : [
            {path: '', redirectTo: 'ticket-search', pathMatch: 'full'},
            { path: 'ticket-search',  component: TicketSearchComponent },
            { path: 'ticket-list/:simpleOrDetailed', component: TicketListComponent },
        ]}
    ])
],
exports: [
    RouterModule
]
})
```

If needed, here is my app level routing:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
 RouterModule.forRoot([
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'administration', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'administration', component: AdministrationComponent},
        {path: 'web-report', component: WebReportComponent }
    ])],
   exports: [
RouterModule
  ]
 })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. I actually needed to change my route at the app level to:

```
 {path: 'web-report', redirectTo: 'web-report/ticket-search', pathMatch: 'full'}
```